# SQL SELECT Query on related table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a question for which I found a rather long solution of which I don't think that it is good practise. 
However I feel there must be a syntax available that is able to solve this issue right away without too many complexities. 
I bumped into this problem a few times already, and I'd like to know for once and for all.

I have a table called "T_STOP_LOSS", in which I have three columns "LIVES_FROM", "LIVES_TO" and "SL_VALUE" (All number types + the column containing ID with AutoNumber type). 
I want to retrieve the record containing the SL_VALUE where a variable value lies in the interval between LIVES_FROM and LIVES_TO.

```
ID  LIVES_FROM   LIVES_TO   NR_COUNTRIES_FROM   NR_COUNTRIES_TO SL_VALUE
1   0   999 2   2   39,3
12  0   999 3   3   34,6
23  0   999 4   4   29,6
34  0   999 5   9   25,7
45  0   999 10  100 22,17
46  1000    1499    2   2   31,1
2   1000    1499    3   3   27,4
13  1000    1499    4   4   23,3
24  1000    1499    5   9   20,4
35  1000    1499    10  100 17,5
36  1500    1999    2   2   23,6
47  1500    1999    3   3   20,7
3   1500    1999    4   4   17,7
14  1500    1999    5   9   15,4
25  1500    1999    10  100 13,3
26  2000    2999    2   2   23,6
37  2000    2999    3   3   20,7
48  2000    2999    4   4   17,7
4   2000    2999    5   9   15,4
15  2000    2999    10  100 13,3
```

Normally I would use:

```
lNr_Lives = <Something> '(Retrieved via Textbox)
sSQL_Select = "SELECT SLVALUE FROM T_STOP_LOSS WHERE LIVES_FROM <= " & LNr_Lives & " AND LIVES_TO >= " & LNr_Lives & ";"
```

However, LIVES_FROM and LIVES_TO are related to the table NR_LIVES through a foreign key.
The above statement will never work because table 'NR_LIVES' contains an ID field as Primary Key, which is used to link to the T_STOP_LOSS table. 
(The columns in NR_LIVES are named: ID, NR_LIVES_FROM and NR_LIVES_TO (not that it matters)).

```
ID  NR_LIVES_FROM   NR_LIVES_TO
1   0   999
2   1000    1499
3   1500    1999
4   2000    2999
```

Please tell me, what would you consider to be the briefest way to access the real value of LIVES_FROM and LIVES_TO that is stored in the NR_LIVES table and get my SELECT statement working the way I expect it (Return the record that contains the SL for the right interval).

I hope that my question is clear. If not, don't hesitate to mention.

Comment: Please do not use pictures, it is not possible to reproduce the problem from a picture whereas even the most badly formatted data can be cut and pasted.

Comment: Let's clarify: T_STOP_LOSS.ID is related to NR_LIVES.ID? What is the difference between the NR_LIVES_FROM and T_STOP_LOSS.LIVES_FROM? Are they redundant fields? Exactly which value are you trying to match against?

Comment: What happened to the sample data?

Comment: The T_STOP_LOSS.LIVES_FROM is linked to the NR_LIVES.LIVES_FROM via the lookupwizard. What you see in the T_STOP_LOSS table are the values defined in the NR_LIVES table, but it actually contains an ID from the NR_LIVES table. The same is true for the LIVES_TO. Since these intervals may slightly shift in the future, I did this so it is possible to change the value once in the NR_LIVES table and the changes will automatically have effect in the T_STOP_LOSS table.

Comment: @Remou: Sample data? You mean the pictures? Well, I deleted them?

Comment: Pictures are not a good idea, sample data is a good idea. Paste data, not pictures. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I see, I'm trying to do that now but it looks kinda weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Nicolas, I found what I needed.

```
Dim cQueries                    As clsQueries
Dim oRst                        As DAO.Recordset
Dim sSQL_Select                 As String
Dim LNr_Lives                   As Long
Dim iNr_Countries               As Integer
Dim i As Integer


If Not IsNull(Me.txt_Nr_Lives) Then
    LNr_Lives = Me.txt_Nr_Lives
Else
    MsgBox "No number of lives defined!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.cbb_Nr_Countries) Then
    iNr_Countries = Me.cbb_Nr_Countries
Else
    MsgBox "No number of countries defined!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

Set cQueries = New clsQueries
sSQL_Select = "SELECT " & _
                    "* " & _
                "FROM " & _
                    "T_STOP_LOSS " & _
                "INNER JOIN " & _
                    "NR_LIVES ON (T_STOP_LOSS.LIVES_FROM = NR_LIVES.ID) " & _
                " WHERE " & _
                    "NR_LIVES.NR_LIVES_FROM <= " & LNr_Lives & _
                " AND " & _
                    "NR_LIVES.NR_LIVES_TO >= " & LNr_Lives & _
                " AND " & _
                    "T_STOP_LOSS.NR_COUNTRIES_FROM <= " & iNr_Countries & _
                " AND " & _
                    "T_STOP_LOSS.NR_COUNTRIES_TO >= " & iNr_Countries & ";"

Set oRst = cQueries.Select_Statement(sSQL_Select)
oRst.MoveFirst

Do While Not oRst.EOF
    Me.txt_FSL = oRst![SL_VALUE]
    oRst.MoveNext
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you want to do some simple join queries. First check out these references [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) and [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/join-tables-and-queries-HA010096320.aspx) to get you more familiar with the approach.

Secondly, there is generally no reason to have the extra 'Lookup' columns in the child tables as these values can be accessed from an appropriate JOIN query.

I suspect the query you are looking for is:

```
SELECT SLVALUE FROM
T_STOP_LOSS
INNER JOIN
NR_LIVES 
ON T_STOP_LOSS.ID=NR_LIVES.ID
WHERE 
NR_LIVES_FROM <=  LNr_Lives  
AND 
NR_LIVES_TO >= LNr_Lives ;
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, I'll have a look on my smartphone because my internet at home is not ok yet (just moved).

Comment: This looks like the syntax I've been looking for. I'm not so experienced in databases yet but I'm going to look deeper into it. Acceptance on the way after I tested!

Comment: +1 for helping me on the right track and it was almost what  I needed, many thanks. I will post another reply despite, because I had to join on: T_STOP_LOSS.LIVES_FROM = NR_LIVES.ID. If I join on the ID's, I don't get the correct result because the ID (auto increment) fields of the two tables are not the same.